# Returning the necessary data from a Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I want to be able to return some data from a controller so that I can create a line graph in JavaScript using the gon gem.

I have two models:

```
account:  id[PK, int], name[string], credit[boolean], active[boolean]
balance: id[PK, int], account_id[FK, int], balance[decimal], date[date]

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :balances
end

class Balance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

For all the dates in "balances", I want to return the sum of the accounts where active is "t" and where active is "f" and the difference.

This is some sample data:

```
Account.create(name: 'Natwest', active: 't', credit: 'f')
Account.create(name: 'Cash', active: 't', credit: 'f')
Account.create(name: 'Capital One CC', active: 't', credit: 't')
Balance.create(account_id: '1', balance: '100', date: '31/10/2015')
Balance.create(account_id: '1', balance: '500', date: '30/11/2015')
Balance.create(account_id: '1', balance: '50', date: '31/12/2015')
Balance.create(account_id: '2', balance: '500', date: '30/09/2015')
Balance.create(account_id: '2', balance: '240', date: '31/10/2015')
Balance.create(account_id: '2', balance: '50', date: '30/11/2015')
Balance.create(account_id: '3', balance: '200', date: '30/09/2015')
Balance.create(account_id: '3', balance: '150', date: '31/10/2015')
Balance.create(account_id: '3', balance: '140', date: '30/11/2015')
```

These are the expected results:

```
- 30/09/2015:
    active: 500
    inactive: 200
    difference: 300
- 31/10/2015:
    active: 340
    inactive: 150
    difference: 190
- 30/11/2015:
    active: 550
    inactive: 140
    difference: 410
- 31/12/2015:
    active: 50
    inactive: 0
    difference: 50
```

I think I need to create a hash to achieve this and I can return the dates in ascending order as shown below but I'm not sure how to return the `active`, `inactive` and `difference` values.

```
@test = Hash[
  Balance.joins(:account).order(date: :asc).group_by(&:date)
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
  def hash_template
    Hash.new do |k, v|
      k[v] = Hash.new { |k1,v1| k1[v1] = 0 }
    end
  end

Balance.joins(:account)
        .order(date: :asc)
        .group_by(&:date)
        .each_with_object(hash_template) do |stats, memo|
  date = stats.first
  users = stats.second
  memo[date][:active] = users.select { |b| b.account.active }.sum(&:balance)
  memo[date][:inactive] = users.select { |b| !b.account.active }.sum(&:balance)
  memo[date][:difference] = memo[date][:active] - memo[date][:inactive]
end
#=>
{Wed, 30 Sep 2015=>{:active=>700.0, :inactive=>0, :difference=>700.0},   
 Sat, 31 Oct 2015=>{:active=>490.0, :inactive=>0, :difference=>490.0},
 Mon, 30 Nov 2015=>{:active=>690.0, :inactive=>0, :difference=>690.0},
 Thu, 31 Dec 2015=>{:active=>50.0, :inactive=>0, :difference=>50.0}}
```

Comment: Thank you, however looking at your results, they're incorrect and don't match what I should expect. All the inactive results = 0.

Comment: your all account are active. See your question)

Comment: Ah, yes. My error. I actually wanted to return the balance where for `b.account.credit` and `!b.account.credit` and the difference but I've managed to modify your code to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Rather than toss out code, explain why your code is a good solution. You want to educate so the OP knows what to do next time rather than simply solve this particular problem.